# Why does the align-items property not work? It is stuck at the top of the page similar to, align-items: flex-start;

Tags: css

This is a test for flexbox programs.

Here is my code:

```css
.box-1 {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: green;
  padding-left: 25px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding-right: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box-3 {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="box-2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="box-3">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

I need help on this for a flexbox project.
Is there any details I am currently missing?
I am new to flexbox, so this may look like very basic code.

Comment: There is no `align-items` in your code; perhaps you mean `align-items: center` instead of `align-content: center`? Note that you want to align the text inside each `box-`, whereas `align-items` can only affect the boxes themselves. Try setting `display: flex; align-items: center;` to the `box-`es too.

Comment: container has not been given a height so there is nothing for the system to align items to. Did you want it to have the viewport height? (100vh)?